# DateDiff in excel/python

Tags: python, google-sheets, date-difference

I have the following table in which for every `Name` I would like to know the total days of employment, and current status (Employed or Not Employed).

```
Date       Name    EmploymentType
01-1-18    A       Hired
10-1-18    A       Fired
11-1-18    A       Hired
15-1-18    A       Fired
25-2-18    A       Hired
25-2-18    B       Hired
05-2-18    C       Hired
15-2-18    C       Fired
```

I would like the following result:

```
Total Days Employed    Name    Current Status
15                     A       Employed
0                      B       Employed
10                     C       Not Employed
```

It would be great if I can know how to do this in Google sheets or python, both appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution but you can play from this or understand a little the logic behind

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame({"date":["2018-01-01", "2018-01-10","2018-01-11",
                            "2018-01-15", "2018-02-25","2018-02-25",
                            "2018-02-05", "2018-02-15"],
                    "name":["a"]*5+["b"]+["c"]*2,
                    "status":['hired', "fired","hired", "fired",
                              "hired", "hired", "hired", "fired"]})

def fun(x):
    x = x.sort_values("date")\
         .reset_index(drop=True)
    res =[None]*2
    # this tell you the last status
    res[0] = x["status"].iloc[-1]
    # here we count days between any hired and fired
    res[1] = x["date"].diff().dt.days.values[1::2].sum()
    return(res)


df["date"] =  df["date"].astype("M8[us]")

out = df.groupby("name").apply(lambda x: fun(x)).reset_index()

out[["status", "days"]] = out[0].apply(pd.Series)
del out[0]
out
      name status  days
0    a  hired  13.0
1    b  hired   0.0
2    c  fired  10.0
```

I will consider to add the today date in case the employee is still working.